# Infer types based on condition in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question regarding typescript

I want IDE to navigate me to correct service instance when toggling uistate mockEnabled flag.
Why is that? and how can i correct it?
uistate is behaving as expected, its is returning the correct instance, code is working fine,  i need assistance in IDE by typescript
IDE, its not doing that, it takes me to fakeVehicleConfigSetsApiService always when i click on it.

This is my code

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class VehicleConfigRequestItemService {
  

  constructor(
    private uiState: UiStateService,
    private vehicleConfigSetsApiService: VehicleConfigSetsApiService,
    private fakeVehicleConfigSetsApiService: FakeVehicleConfigSetsApiService
  ) {
  }

  private get vehicleConfigSetApi():
    | VehicleConfigSetsApiService
    | FakeVehicleConfigSetsApiService {
    return this.uiState.config().isMockEnabled
      ? this.fakeVehicleConfigSetsApiService
      : this.vehicleConfigSetsApiService;
  }


  fetchItems(
    success: (items: VehicleConfigRequestItem[]) => void,
    error: (error) => void,
    parentItemId: string | undefined,
    initial
  ): void {
    if (Util.isPresent(parentItemId, "parentItemId")) {
      this.vehicleConfigSetApi
        .fetchVehicleConfigRequests$(parentItemId)
        .subscribe(()=>{});
    }
  }
}
```